# Equation with n on bottom with a0=0 and a1=1

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have this equation $a_{n+2}=a_{n+1}+6a_n$ for $a_0=0,a_1=1$.

I should $a_{0+2}=a_{0+1}+6a_0$ (1) relation.The case $a_1=1$ it should be $a_{1+2}=a_{1+1}+6a_1$.

I just replace it. What should I have done?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  I've formatted the first line of your post to show how math notation can be use (as [introduced in this note]()).  Please check that I did not unintentionally change your meaning, and edit the rest of your post using similar syntax.  I don't follow your meaning.

Comment: same as above for my editing, which superimposed in time with the above (sorry)

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE!  Could you clarify what your question is?  As it stands, I'm not sure I understand what you are asking.

Comment: hi, it is retroactive

Comment: This is not clear.  Taking $n=0$ your recursion gives $a_2=a_1+6a_0$.  From the initial conditions, that would tell us that $a_2=1+6\times 0=1$.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  As you can see from the comments, nobody is sure what you are asking.

Comment: What do you want to do? If the task is to calculate for example $a_2$, $a_3$ and $a_4$ then you are on a correct path:

$$a_2 = \{ \text{ take $n=0$ } \} = a_{0+2} = a_{0+1} + 6 a_0 = a_1 + 6 a_0 = 1 + 6 \times 0 = 1.$$

$$a_3 = \{ \text{ take $n=1$ } \} = a_{1+2} = a_{1+1} + 6 a_1 = a_2 + 6 a_1 = 1 + 6 \times 1 = 7.$$

$$a_4 = \{ \text{ take $n=2$ } \} = a_{2+2} = a_{2+1} + 6 a_2 = a_3 + 6 a_2 = 7 + 6 \times 1 = 13.$$

Comment: @md2perpe thank you a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

A closed-form of the n-th term of this sequences is in http://oeis.org/A015441 .